# How do I add divisions to a circular plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting the density of observations throughout the year and I want to add radial lines which delimit the months of the year.

My dataframe is called `Data.1`

`Data.1$YearDayDeg` is a column which has dates converted into degrees.

This is my code:

```
circ = as.circular(Data.1$YearDayDeg, units = "degrees")

circdens = density(circ, bw = 100, control.circular = list(units = "degrees"))

plot(circdens, tol = 0.2, zero = 1.57079633, rotation = "clock")
```

This produced [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l54fO.jpg) but I want to add radial lines to display months with labels and get rid of the stupid automatic title and add my own custom title so it ends up looking something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMuwj.jpg).

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the quenstions:

- radial lines -> use `segments`   display months -> use `text`
- custom title -> parameter `main="Your title"` in function `plot`
- get rid of labels showing 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees ->  use
  `axes=FALSE`
  plotting circular objects seems to work via `plot.circular`, which has - as usual - the axes parameter, where `axes=FALSE` suppresses axes (with labels).
- start and rotational direction of labels: updated the maths. Always recommend to plot first with axis to check custom labels, and only then suppress axes ;-)

See also online help for details: simply run `?plot`, `?par`, `?plot`, `?plot.circular`, ...).
Hope that helps!

```
# always a good idea to state which packages are used...
require(circular)
require(stats)

# reproducible sampel data
set.seed(123)
dta <- runif(n=360,min=0,max=360)  

# get "plottable" data
circ = as.circular(dta, units = "degrees")
circdens = density(circ, bw = 100, control.circular = list(units = "degrees"))

# plot
par.xpd.old <- par("xpd") # default is FALSE
par(xpd=NA,  # clip plotting only at device region, not to plot region (default). See ?par
    mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1 + c(1,0,2,0))    # increase margin space for outward shifted month labels; default is c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1

plot(circdens, zero=pi/2, tol = 0.2, 
     rotation = "clock",
     main=NA, #"Your Title",    # your title (displays template used)
     sub="your subtitle",       # and some other stuff to play around
     col="red", lty="solid",    # see ?plot and ?par
     # xlab="x axis label instead of N, Bandwidth and units",
     ylab="y axis label instead of Density circular",
     # template=c("none", "geographics", "clock12", "clock24")[1], #does not help much regarding the question
     # units="",  "" -> pi units
     axes=FALSE) # always check frist (axes=TRUE) if real labels and custom labels match... 

# if you want to move the "main title", try also plot(... main=NA...), and then:
mtext(text="Do it yourself title", side=3, line=4, cex=1.5, font=2)

# radial lines
segments(x0=0, y0=0, 
         x1=cos(seq(from=0, to=2*pi, length.out=12+1)) * 1.5,   # do some maths...
         y1=sin(seq(from=0, to=2*pi, length.out=12+1)) * 1.5,   # *1.5: extend radial lines outwards
         col="blue")

# mont labels
text(cos(seq(from=2*pi-pi/12, to=0-pi/12, length.out=12+1)+pi/2) * 1.5,  # offset -pi/12 places labels in between dividing lines
     sin(seq(from=2*pi-pi/12, to=0-pi/12, length.out=12+1)+pi/2) * 1.5,  # *1.5 places the months a little bit outwards
     labels=c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
              "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", NA), # need 12+1 data
     col="blue")

par(xpd=par.xpd.old)  # restore previous xpd settings

# --- end ---
```

Comment: Great thanks! Any ideas of getting rid of the labels showing 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees?

Also the segment labels start in the third segment and rotate anti-clockwise instead of clockwise. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Updtaed my answer to address the additional questins.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to circular, there is another library called plotrix which can help achieve the desired result:

```
library(plotrix)
testlen <- c(rnorm(36)*2+5)
testpos <- seq(0,350,by=10)
polar.plot(testlen,testpos,main="Test Polar Plot",lwd=3,line.col=4)
```

You can then modify the parameters you pass to `polar.plot` to change the title, axes, etc.